# Pandas filter by condition in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a matrix/dataframe with times and values:

```
     # time             # Value
M = [[2018-08-08 12:00:00, 5],
     [2018-08-08 12:00:00, 7],
     [2018-08-08 13:00:00, 2],]
```

I want to group by hour, then calculate the mean value of the group, and then modify/reduce each group so that it has only values <= this mean.

Current version:

```
grouped = M.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='1h'))
means = grouped['value'].mean().values # np.array([6, 2])
```

Here I'm stuck. I get the mean values for each group. But I don't know how to reduce the "grouped" so that the condition applies that grouped[grouped['value'] <= mean] for that group.

Appreciate any suggestions.

---

Expected output:

```
N = [[2018-08-08 12:00:00, 5], # as 5 <= 6 where 6 is the mean of the first group
     [2018-08-08 13:00:00, 2]] # as 2 is <= 2 where 2 is the mean of the second group
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame` filled by aggregated values, so [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) working very nice:

```
M = [['2018-08-08 12:00:00', 5],
     ['2018-08-08 12:00:00', 7],
     ['2018-08-08 13:00:00', 2]]

M = pd.DataFrame(M, columns=['time','value'])
M['time'] = pd.to_datetime(M['time'])
print (M)
                 time  value
0 2018-08-08 12:00:00      5
1 2018-08-08 12:00:00      7
2 2018-08-08 13:00:00      2

s = M.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='1h'))['value'].transform('mean')
print (s)
0    6
1    6
2    2
Name: value, dtype: int64

mean = 5
df = M[s <= mean]
print (df)
                 time  value
2 2018-08-08 13:00:00      2
```

EDIT:

You can also compare by columns values:

```
df1 = M[M['value'] <= s]
print (df1)
                 time  value
0 2018-08-08 12:00:00      5
2 2018-08-08 13:00:00      2
```

Comment: Thanks!! Edited the expected output in the question above, appreciate if you could check. Sorry I didn't make it clearer

Comment: Nice thanks! As I see I'd need to apply groupby first time to do the transform, and then a second time after I apply the boolean index to get the hourly group back, correct?

Comment: hmmm, your solution with no `transform` only aggregate rows - it means final DataFrame have less rows like original DataFrame, so not possible comparing. So `transform` here is necessary for return aggregate values with equal size. Practically it duplicates values for each group with aggregated values - like in your sample data `6` for first group.